# Multiple buttons with hover effect Javascript

Tags: javascript, foreach

I want to create animations on buttons in Javascript. When I hover any buttons animations must follow cursor for now I create working sample with one buttons here: https://jsfiddle.net/sL0uebh4/

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn');

btn.onmousemove = function(e) {
  const x = e.pageX - btn.offsetLeft;
  const y = e.pageY - btn.offsetTop;
  btn.style.setProperty('--x', x + 'px')
  btn.style.setProperty('--y', y + 'px')
}
```

```css
.btn {
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #666;
  margin: 10px;
}

.btn::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: var(--y);
  left: var(--x);
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  background: #ff0000;
}

.btn:hover::before {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<a href#="" class="btn">Click</a>
<a href#="" class="btn">Click2</a>
<a href#="" class="btn">Click3</a>
```

I know I need change `querySelector()` to `querySelectorAll` and in my code use somehow `forEach()` but all my attempts failed and I need a little hint how it should looks.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"Help others reproduce the problem ... Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem ... If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so - **but also copy the code into the question itself.** Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time. Use Stack Snippets to make a live demo of inline JavaScript / HTML / CSS."_

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href#="" onmousemove="animation(this.id)"  id="btn1" class="btn">
Click
</a>
<a href#=""  onmousemove="animation(this.id)"  id="btn2"class="btn">
Click2
</a>
<a href#=""  onmousemove="animation(this.id)" id="btn3" class="btn">
Click3
</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
function animation(id){

 const btn = document.getElementById(id)
  console.log(btn)
  btn.onmousemove = function(e) {
  const x = e.pageX;
  const y = e.pageY;
  btn.style.setProperty('--x', x + 'px')
  btn.style.setProperty('--y', y + 'px')
    }

}
```

Comment: As in code above my buttons didn't have ID and I'm not able to add Ids to theme

Comment: I will edit my example, can you add events though?

Comment: I can add events to button but not ID